# Moving a single instance Redis database to a sharded database?

Tags: java, redis

I have a non-sharded Redis database and I'd like copy the data to a sharded database.  I've looked around, but the best practice I could find was to export the dump file to Json and then reload it to the new sharded db instance, so key hashes can be preserved.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, and what is your question?

Comment: This is something that redis-rdb-tools can/should support. I created an issue to track this https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/issues/14.

Comment: I don't understand the question very well but I've the feeling that the 2.6 MIGRATE command could help. http://redis.io/commands/migrate

Comment: My question is, how should I move data in a redis database to a sharded instance.

Answer (score 0):

Redis Cluster is still under development so in the mean time the following approaches can be taken -

1. If you used PHP , JAVA or scala then , Predis , Jedis and scala-redis support client side sharding , i.e. uses hashing on client side to distribute load evenly between multiple redis servers.
2. Check out Redis-Sharding if you don't use the above languages -

https://github.com/kni/redis-sharding